# Does Google index Web Apps with Ember JS?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to know if Google has any problem to index Web Apps that have been developed with [Ember JS](http://emberjs.com/).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Answer (score 2):

Posting to this question after 5 years because this is the first page that pops up on google when I search for emberjs google indexing. I would like to mention that the ajax-crawling method mentioned in the above answer is deprecated. New google crawlers will render JS based websites as it renders on a browser and uses that information to crawl as explained in this article [Google deprecates ajax crawling scheme.](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)