# Running Server Side Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, seo, web-crawler

I've developed a large javascript library that I'm using to create a number of visualizations was well as dynamic content for my webpage.

I have recently noticed that the google crawler does not run javascript and a lot of my pages are being index without the onload content that my library creates.

I'm in a .NET environment and am wondering what the solution for this is? In my mind I see:

1. Convert the entire javascript library to a service side language (this would be a large undertaking)
2. using something like Node mixed with .net to run server side javascript (not sure how this would work)
3. Use something like Node.NET: https://github.com/dnewcome/Node.net (pretty old, not sure if it would work)

Are there any other solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from this question:
[Does Google index Web Apps with Ember JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789322/does-google-index-web-apps-with-ember-js)

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ should help you.

Comment: I saw this: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot But it says to create a html snapshot, which amounts to the same problem as above